# How deep can Entities be nested with normalizationContext Groups

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm using api-platform w/ Symfony 4 and have a desire to embed multiple relations as one references another which references another... It would be ideal for the response to provide a multidimensional layer of data.

I am using serialization groups, as seen here: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#embedding-relations, but can only seem to get a single depth out of it.

Here is an example of my entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups": {"invoice"}}
 * )
 */
class Invoices {
    /**
     * @Groups({"invoice"})
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\InvoiceItems", mappedBy="invoice")
     * @Groups({"invoice"})
     */
    private $items;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource
 */
class InvoiceItems {
    /**
     * @Groups({"invoice"})
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\EventRegistrations", inversedBy="invoiceItem")
     * @Groups({"invoice"})
     */
    private $registrations;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource
 */
class EventRegistrations {
    /**
     * @Groups({"invoice"})
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Events", inversedBy="registrations")
     * @Groups({"invoice"})
     */
    private $events;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource
 */
class Events {
    /**
     * @Groups({"invoice"})
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * @Groups({"invoice"})
     */
    private $type;
}
```

This is what I'd like to see when requesting Invoices:

```
{
  id: 1,
  items: [
    {
      id: 1
      registration: {
        id: 1
        event: {
          id: 1
          type: 'outdoor'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but this is all I can seem to get:

```
{
  id: 1,
  items: [
    {
      id: 1
      registration: '/registrations/1'
    }
  ]
}
```

It seems that multidimensional layers of relations is not possible, which just means more queries, but I'm hoping someone out there w/ experience w/ these softwares may be able to offer a suggestion or solution.

Answer (score 0):

Soooo... The example provided works as expected; it will create multidimensional layers in the response. I'm not curently sure why it wasn't working during testing but it's working now.